# Complex SQL Query in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table as below and I want the Products which are having same Lot Numbers in different countries. I need all the records.

Table:

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ Product ID ║ Lot Number ║ Country ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║          1 ║ L01        ║ US      ║
║          2 ║ L02        ║ US      ║
║          3 ║ L01        ║ UK      ║
║          4 ║ L02        ║ US      ║
║          5 ║ L03        ║ UK      ║
║          6 ║ L03        ║ US      ║
║          7 ║ L03        ║ US      ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

Required Output:

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ Product ID ║ Lot Number ║ Country ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║          1 ║ L01        ║ US      ║
║          3 ║ L01        ║ UK      ║
║          5 ║ L03        ║ UK      ║
║          6 ║ L03        ║ US      ║
║          7 ║ L03        ║ US      ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That one is relatively straightforward:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM MyTable t2
    WHERE t1.LotNumber=t2.LotNumber AND t1.Country <> t2.Country
)
```

This is self-explanatory: you want all rows such that there's at least one other row with the same lot number, but a different country. Note that in order to express this in SQL using the same table twice in the same query you need to give your table an alias: in the query above, that's `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: hi @dasblinkenlight I am wondering why the below query is not working. Any idea?
    `SELECT productid, lotnumber, country 
    FROM MyProducts t1
    WHERE t1.ProductID in(
    SELECT ProductID FROM MyProducts t2
    WHERE t1.LotNumber=t2.LotNumber AND t1.Country <> t2.Country
    )`

Comment: @Rams The logic connecting the table `t1` from the outer query to the table `t2` from the subquery is strange: I do not see what rows it should be returning, given that the constraints go both ways (subquery constraints the outer query by ID, and the outer query constraints the subquery by LotNumber and Country).